# How can I change style of PushButton in Installshield?

Tags: button, dialog, installshield

I created custom Dialog in my Basic MSI project and placed 3-4 pushbuttons on it. Now I want to change pushbutton style - for example I want to have oval buttons instead of rectangular, I want to have possibility of changing their color, I want to add small image on it etc... Set of push button properties is limited as I can see - there are Height, Width, Visible, TabStop TextStyle and some other simple properties.

How can I do it in InstallShield Professional Edition?

Answer (score 0):

The UI available to Windows Installer is not capable of that. We're moving that direction in our Advanced UI project's UI, but currently offer only relatively standard buttons at this point.